# Prevent IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, errno, ioerror

I can't figure why in my code I get a weird `IOError [Errno 4] Interrupted system call`.

The example below is a dummy one, but it allows (at least on my Linux laptop) to reproduce the error:

```
import subprocess as sp

def dummyfun():
    p1 = sp.Popen(['ls','-lah'], stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdout=sp.PIPE, close_fds=True)
    p2 = sp.Popen(['grep','.'],stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE, close_fds=True)
    p1.stdout.close()
    return p2.stdout

def dummyfun2(fo):
    for l in fo:
        print l,

def dummyfun3():
    fo = dummyfun()
    dummyfun2(fo)
    fo.close()
```

Calling `dummyfun3` basically just prints on the screen a list of all the files whith a dot in their name (in my case I am in a folder with about 100 files, and all of them have some extension and therefore a dot).

If I call the function as `dummyfun3()` it just works.

However if I call it in a loop like:

```
for i in range(1000):
    dummyfun3()
```

after a few iterations the code stops (usually `i` is between 5 and 15) displaying the following error message:

```
<ipython-input-213-a47ea086386d> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(1000):
----> 2     dummyfun3()
      3 

<ipython-input-205-21366f183162> in dummyfun3()
      1 def dummyfun3():
      2     fo = dummyfun()
----> 3     dummyfun2(fo)
      4     fo.close()
      5 

<ipython-input-204-1c08d906020b> in dummyfun2(fo)
      1 def dummyfun2(fo):
      2     for l in fo:
----> 3         print l,
      4 

IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

Why such an error and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Works for me `:-(`  Linux (32 or 64), Python 2.7, in a directory with 115 files.  Are you sure the error occurs on the `print l,` line?  That looks more like an ipython bug.  Does it work on the command line?

Comment: you are right.. working with python2.7 instead of ipython it works fine... so this means that my code is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, your code is fine.  It's still bad because it looks like some bug in ipython, or some otherwise bogus interaction.  You should try the latest development version of ipython and if it still fails, report it as a bug, I'd say.

Comment: @ArminRigo thanks :) if you submit an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs on the `print l,` line: that looks more like an ipython bug.  As you said in the comments already, it works on the command line.  You should try the latest development version of ipython and if it still fails, report it as a bug, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

IPython developer here. For what it's worth, it's unlikely that this is an IPython bug - at least I'm unable to reproduce it in either master, nor on 0.13.2 (64-bit Debian/sid). Luca filed this as [issue #3884](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3884), so we'll see where it goes from there.

Comment: thanks. As I answered in the bug tracking system, I followed your advices and seen that the issue arises only when running with --pylab option.